# Node Recurly Create Transaction using Stored Billing Info

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, recurly

I want to create transaction using Recurly stoed billing information. i'm using node Reculry module call node-recurly
https://github.com/robrighter/node-recurly

Below please find the my code

```
       recurly.transactions.create({
            'account_code': orgId,
            'amount_in_cents': 200,
            'currency': 'AUD'
          }, function (err, response) {
              if (err) {
                return res.send({
                  success :false,
                  message :message_common.coupon_create_err,
                  data: err,
                  status :status_common.error_res
                });
              } else {
                return res.send({
                  success :true,
                  message :message_common.coupon_create_success,
                  data: [],
                  status :status_common.success_res
                });
              }
          });
```

it return below error message,

```
 {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
      "date": "Mon, 05 Dec 2016 11:34:53 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
      "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
      "connection": "close",
      "set-cookie": [
        "__cfduid=deb9088318b3890486d479eb2a9a4aed11480937692; expires=Tue, 05-Dec-17 11:34:52 GMT; path=/; domain=.recurly.com; HttpOnly"
      ],
      "x-api-version": "2.0",
      "content-language": "en-US",
      "x-ratelimit-limit": "2000",
      "x-ratelimit-remaining": "1996",
      "x-ratelimit-reset": "1480937940",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "x-request-id": "aopr1tvaaooktujne13g",
      "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload",
      "server": "cloudflare-nginx",
      "cf-ray": "30c73103cdd42384-FRA"
    },
    "data": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<error>\n  <symbol>invalid_xml</symbol>\n  <description>The provided XML was invalid.</description>\n  <details>Unacceptable tag &lt;account_code&gt;</details>\n</error>"
  }
```

Comment: I'd say *"The provided XML was invalid. Unacceptable tag <account_code>"* is a very specific error.

Comment: so, what is your suggestions?

Comment: That you think about what the error message means? Do a search for the error message? Read the API documentation? Take Wireshark and look at the HTTP packages and compare? All of these things are basic debugging. That's *your* job. You should have done them before coming here to ask a question.

Comment: sound's good.. :)

Answer (score 0):

there is gives not XML data formating error if you know about to libxmljs modules for node then use with node-recurly that help to solving problems ex,

```
var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");
var xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
           '<root>' +
               '<child foo="bar">' +
                   '<grandchild baz="fizbuzz">grandchild      content</grandchild>' +
               '</child>' +
               '<sibling>with content!</sibling>' +
           '</root>';
```

use create transactional code replace with xml variable values.

```
// Example with Stored Billing Info
<transaction>
  <amount_in_cents>100</amount_in_cents>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <account>
    <account_code>1</account_code>
  </account>
</transaction>

// Example with new Billing Info
<transaction>
  <amount_in_cents>1000</amount_in_cents>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <account>
    <account_code>1</account_code>
    <billing_info>
      <first_name>Verena</first_name>
      <last_name>Example</last_name>
      <address1>123 Main St.</address1>
      <city>San Francisco</city>
      <zip>94105</zip>
      <country>US</country>
      <number>4111-1111-1111-1111</number>
      <verification_value>123</verification_value>
      <month>11</month>
      <year>2015</year>
    </billing_info>
  </account>
</transaction>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, could you do a small sample here ?

Comment: if you do with unofficial node.js api then check your recurly.transactions.create function their is account_code tag problems check and make sure your "orgId" is string.